# Wrinkled seat cover. Solution?

Tags: seat

I have a seat cover that was installed by someone who didn't do a very good job. The result is what we have in the picture below. Is there any way of fixing the wrinkle without removing the whole thing and reinstalling?

Specifically, would heating with a hair dryer/hot towel work because that seems to work on small wrinkles as shown here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GXEL4qqzuUo

[image]

Comment: Can't you go back to the installer and request that the job is done correctly?

Comment: Yes, but I'm afraid he's going to mess it up even more. I really would rather have it this way than give the car back to him at this point.

Comment: Why do I think this looks less like a fitment issue and more of a cut issue? Looks to me whomever cut the pattern and sewed it together didn't do a very good job.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2, that's probably right. Which is why I'm hoping I can shrink it with heat or something?